# Mock HttpClient with multiple clients to be used in single controller

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, moq, dotnet-httpclient

My unit test is-

```
 String xmlText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\PrashantWorkspace\Weather.xml");
            var mockFactory = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();
            var mockHttpMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
            mockHttpMessageHandler.Protected()
                .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
                .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                    Content = new StringContent(xmlText, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml"),
                });            
            var client = new HttpClient(mockHttpMessageHandler.Object);
            mockFactory.Setup(_ => _.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(client);
            WeatherController wController = new WeatherController(_logger.Object, _configuration.Object, mockFactory.Object);
            var result = await wController.Get("1", "2", false);
            Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
```

How can I pass another xml that will be used by 2nd api call in my controller?

Comment: Use SetupSequence on the mock

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you have *another endpoint* (and not the second call to the *same endpoint*), then you can pass a predicate that will match on the `RequestUri` of the `HttpRequestMessage`:

```cs
_httpMessageHandlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();

var booksResponse = new HttpResponseMessage
{
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
    Content = new StringContent(
        @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?> ")
};

_httpMessageHandlerMock
    .Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
        "SendAsync",
        ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(x =>
            x.RequestUri != null && x.RequestUri.ToString().Contains("books")),
        ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(booksResponse);

var authorsResponse = new HttpResponseMessage
{
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
    Content = new StringContent(
        @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?> ")
};

_httpMessageHandlerMock
    .Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
        "SendAsync",
        ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(x =>
            x.RequestUri != null && x.RequestUri.ToString().Contains("authors")),
        ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(authorsResponse);

_client = new HttpClient(_httpMessageHandlerMock.Object) {BaseAddress = new Uri("http://tempuri")};
```